# How to integrate Robotlegs with Molehill?

Tags: actionscript-3, molehill

I'd like to extend Robotlegs (1.5.2) SignalContext to allow AGAL / Molehill 3D. There's an Away3d port out there as well as the start of the a Starling compatible robotlegs build - but this looks incomplete. At the very least I imagine this requires a custom SignalContext and MediatorMap but I'd like to see if others are thinking about it (possible next major release of Robotlegs?)

Any ideas appreciated on how to get this going

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

M-odel
V-iew
C-ontroller
S-service

Signals are basically injected variables at the end of the day and everything else just gets split apart just as usual.

Stage2D, Stage3D, StageVideo = Views.

AGAL / Shaders aka The wall and the paint that goes on it (classification view)

However if it is a complex Away3D 4.x project I wouldn't touch a framework for simplicity sakes and speed. Adopt strong folderisation relaxed mvc folder structures on your own and just code up something using a few singletons and maybe a factory pattern where and when needed.

You also need to weigh up the time required to build the project using Robotleg/Pure MVC etc, how much time will be fighting with the framework (which usually ends up being quite a bit) over actually doing work to meet the projects goals.

I often build to strong folderisation a relaxed mvmu (models,vies,managers,utils) in such projects which gives better performance and achieves RAD (Rapid Application Development) and hire freelancers to work on them. Some turn round and go I have no idea what is going on here. If the freelancer is unable to understand the concept of 4 folders (models,views,managers & utils) with sub folders named in relation to the task eg view->ui, models->constants, models->config, managers->xml, managers->navigation, managers->auto_navigation, utils->CreateReflectionBitmap etc etc. They have earned themselves a quick ticket back to the looking for a job board.

Structure:

```
    main.as (entry point)
    com [dir]
     --- greensock [dir] (example of 3rd party api location)
     --- application [dir]
         --- application.as (instantiator and startup handler)
         --- models [dir]
         --- views [dir]
         --- managers [dir]
         --- utils [dir]
```

I would suggest signing up on the Robotlegs site and ask lots of questions there, lots of good support there and the google group is also useful.

Good luck.

D